# C++ game code not working

Tags: c++

I'm working on a game for an assignment and I've ran into an issue with function overriding in C++.

I have the following structure:

```
class GameEntity
{
public:
    bool GameEntity::TakeHit(int dmg);
};

class Enemy : public GameEntity
{
    bool Enemy::TakeHit(int dmg);

};
```

When from another class I create an instance of an Enemy, store it in a GameEntity vector, then call TakeHit() on it, it's calling the GameEntity version of it. I'm used to Java where this would call the other version, am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Other questions don't really cover this so I've created my own.

It's probably something pretty simple I'm guessing, so apologies for the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make `TakeHit` a virtual member function.

   ```
   // You don't need the scope specifier GameEntity::
   // Make it pure virtual to force sub-classes to implement them.
   virtual bool TakeHit(int dmg) = 0;
   ```
2. Store pointers to objects, preferably [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), instead of objects. If you store just objects, you suffer from [object slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

The function from `GameEntity` needs the `virtual` keyword.